# ACF of residuals of a correct model specification

Tags: autocorrelation, goodness-of-fit

Why the following sentence is true "If the model is said to be adequate then the estimated residuals should be uncorrelated on average"?

Comment: It means you managed to extract all the information there is to extract. What's left is just random and not representable by a model. If there is correlation in the residuals this regularity can be further used to extract some more information.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: want to post that as an answer? I'll happily upvote. Let's get our ratio of unanswered questions down ;-)